# How to display text with line-breaks in java

Tags: java, swing, text, multiline

I'm working on a text-editor, and I want to display the typed text, what can contain line/breaks. But JLabel does not show multiline text (without using HTML - but I don't want to use). I tried displaying it in an uneditable JTextArea (in a JScrollPane), but it became unscrollable with mouse wheel.

For example:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
JLabel label = new JLabel(textArea.getText());
JFrame.add(new JScrollPane(label));
```

**How can I display multiline text in a scrollable container?**

Comment: *"without using HTML - but I don't want to use"* Why?

Comment: You’ve added your label to the scroll panel, not the `JTextArea`???

Comment: Well, if you tell me how to replace the typed text's line-breaks with <br> elements, I say ok. I thought there is another solution, without HTML.

Comment: Okay, it's a bit strange for me... The whole question is wrong. I was thinking about how can I display text with line-breaks in a scrollable panel. JTextArea in JScrollPane does not scroll. But only with my laptop's touchpad, it works with normal mouse. So the correct question is: Why can't I scroll the panel with my touchpad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say why your JTextArea would stop scrolling, maybe it's a separate issue. This should work fine.

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            JTextArea ta = new JTextArea("a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf\ng\nh");
            ta.setEditable(false);
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            p.add(new JScrollPane(ta));
            f.add(p);
            f.setSize(100, 100);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained *why* your code resolves the problem, instead of just dumping many lines of code and expecting readers to spot the difference.

Comment: @VGR well my code is unrelated to the one OP posted, as it addresses `I tried displaying it in an uneditable JTextArea` part, which didn't have any code attached to it.